# Laravel 4: Any way to run PHP Artisan command in PHP code?

Tags: php, sockets, laravel-4, real-time

I'm fairly new on Laravel's technology regarding real-time application. I'm trying to make a notification system and from what I Google, using some kind of socket server is the best way.

So I'm trying to use this: https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket

But I have no idea how to run it on live server later, since I don't own the server itself I can't run commands like: `php artisan brainsocket:start` in terminal, so I need to figure out how to run that command by using php code?

Or if my method is wrong, how to use that brain-socket in live server?

Comment: If you want to use websockets you really should get a server where you have enough power to run commands like that; to open a long-running socket listening for incoming connections. Doing the same from the web is not really suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with

```
Artisan::call('brainsocket:start', $args);
```

where $args is an array of arguments.

[See the Laravel docs.](http://laravel.com/docs/commands#calling-other-commands)